# html and swf swapping (display html while swf file loads to 100%)

Tags: html, replace, flash, swap

This is what I want to achieve.

1. While the swf file is loading, **wrapper div** displays an html content (e.g. text content).
2. When the swf file has loaded 100%, it replaces the text content within the **wrapper div**, and then plays within the **wrapper div**.
3. When the swf file is finished playing, it is then replaced with the previous text content.

(This is more like html to swf to html swapping within a div)

any thoughts if this is possible or any other workarounds?

Much appreciated to anyone who could share.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is call your div-swapping function from ActionScript in your movie.

You can call is when the movie is 100% loaded and then again from the "last frame" of the movie, so you'd be getting the flash movie to say "show me" and then later "hide me".

Answer (score 0):

Have the HTML and Flash in one div. Since you can't hide a SWF. This trick is to shove it off screen:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="flashWrapper" style="position:relative; left:-2000px;">
        <object>flash embed code</object>
    </div>
    <div id="loading">Flash is loading...</div>
</div>
```

It's more fool-proof to have the SWF call a JS function with the ExternalInterface when it's finished. But you can check it via JS:

```
<script>
    var v = setInterval(function(){
        if(flashMovie.PercentLoaded() == 100){
            document.getElementById("flashWrapper").style.left = "0px";
            document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
            clearInterval(v);
        }
    });
</script>
```

If you are inserting the SWF dynamically be sure to wait a millisecond before accessing it.